# PYTHON nex string splitting

Tags: python

Hello I am learning PYTHON and was learning about string splitting .so I have a hex string named

```
A="aca80202"
```

I want to convert it into a list of 2 characters

```
B=["ac","a8","02",02"]
```

is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with Python you could do it in a simple way using a `for` loop:

```
A="aca80202"
B = []
for i in range(0, len(A), 2):
    B.append(A[i:i+2])
```

EDIT: you could see more ways to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python).